# Matlab: Interleave samples by column

Tags: matlab

In MatLab I have two matrices (matrices can vary in size). I want to grab columns from B and insert them every nth column in A.

Here is a small example:

Case I

Assumptions for this case:

Columns are any multiple of 2 and rows are the same for A and B

A =

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

B =

```
1 2
3 4
```

I want to get this

c =

```
1 2 1 3 4 2
5 6 3 7 8 4
```

The code should also work for a different case such as:

Case II

Assumptions for this case:

Columns are any multiple of 3 and rows are the same for A and B

A =

```
123456789
123456789
```

B =

```
123456
123456
```

C =

```
12312 45634 78956
12312 45634 78956
```

I know MatLab has a reshape and permute functions, but I haven't been able to get the correct results. I know I could use a for loop, or manual concat them by indexing, but was thinking using these functions would have better performance. Any hep would be great.

Comment: is there a specific pattern to the reshape?

Comment: I want to grab columns from B and insert them every nth column in A.

Comment: Are we guaranteed to always have enough values to fill up the new array (and no more)? In the second example, what if `B` had only 3 columns? What would the result look like? What if `B` had 12 columns?

Comment: Ah, you make a very good point and I think this is why I did not understand the problem. You are correct there is a guarantee that B is always smaller in terms of columns and can be inserted "evenly" into A. If B was 3 then divide A by 3 = 3, thus insert after every group of 3. Gosh sorry about this but you made me think through the whole problem. I got it now.

Comment: Well, if you just go by the number of columns of `A` and `B`, then the second example would have 2 columns of `B` following every 3 columns of `A`, right?

Comment: Yes, because 9 and six are divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved the puzzle:

- I converted A and B matrices to vectors, because it's easier to use vector indexing than matrix indexing.
- I prepared a vector of correct indexes of A and B elements using index modulo dimension.

Check the following solution:

```
A = [1 2 3 4
     5 6 7 8];

B =[1 2
    3 4];

aN = size(A, 2);
bN = size(B, 2);

cM = size(A,1);
cN = aN + bN;

a = A(:);
b = B(:);

%Initialize vector C with zeros.
c = zeros(length(a) + length(b), 1);

a_indeces = 1:length(c);
b_indeces = 1:length(c);

%Create array of indeces matches rquiered position of A elements.
a_indeces = a_indeces(mod(a_indeces-1, cN) < aN); %[1:4, 7:10]

%Create array of indeces matches rquiered position of B elements (add aN because B elements follows A elements).
b_indeces = b_indeces(mod(b_indeces-1, cN) < bN) + aN; %[5:6, 11:12]

%Fill c elements as vector.
c(a_indeces) = a;
c(b_indeces) = b;

%Reshape c to matrix.
C = reshape(c, [cM, cN]);
```

---

I found more elegant way, that works better:

```
A = [ 1   2  3  4
      5   6  7  8
      9  10 11 12];

B =[11 12
    13 14
    15 16];

aN = size(A, 2);
bN = size(B, 2);
cN = aN + bN;

a_indeces = 1:cN;
b_indeces = 1:cN;

%Create array of column indeces matches A elements.
a_indeces = a_indeces(mod(a_indeces-1, floor(cN/bN)) < floor(aN/bN));

%Create array of column indeces matches B elements.
b_indeces = b_indeces(mod(b_indeces-1, floor(cN/bN)) >= floor(aN/bN));

C = zeros(size(A,1), cN);

C(:, a_indeces) = A;
C(:, b_indeces) = B;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to first reshape `A` so that it's as wide as `B`, vertically concatenate `B`, and then reshape it to the original height.

```
>> C = reshape([reshape(A, [], size(B,2)); B], size(B,1), [])
C =

   1   2   1   3   4   2
   5   6   3   7   8   4
```

*Assumes `size(A, 1) == size(B, 1)`, naturally.

---

To generalize this, we can find the number of groups of each array by finding the gcd of the numbers of columns:

```
function C = groupcols(A, B)
% interleave columns of A and B such that
%   for m = number of columns of A, and n = number of columns of B
%   the output matrix C has alternating groups of
%     m / gcd(m,n) columns of A, followed by
%     n / gcd(m,n) columns of B
%   if gcd(m,n) == 1, then C will be all columns of A followed by
%     all columns of B

m = size(A,2);
n = size(B,2);
g = gcd(m,n);

C = [reshape(A, size(A,1)*m/g, []); reshape(B, size(B,1)*n/g, [])];
C = reshape(C, size(A,1), []);
```

Using the input:

```
A =

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9

B =

   11   12   13   14   15   16
   11   12   13   14   15   16
```

The output is:

```
1    2    3   11   12    4    5    6   13   14    7    8    9   15   16
1    2    3   11   12    4    5    6   13   14    7    8    9   15   16
```

Since the greatest common divisor of 9 columns and 6 columns is 3, there are 3 groups with 3 columns from A and 2 columns from B.

Comment: This is great, but what if you want to change where you are inserting the columns.

Comment: Change in what way? This evenly spaces the inserted columns, so `size(A,2)` must be evenly divisible by `size(B,2)`. If, for instance, you had 6 columns in `A` and 2 columns in `B`, this would give you three columns of `A`, one column of `B`, three columns of `A`, one column of `B`. If you want different spacings, then I'll probably need an example.

Comment: Your correct, so I added another case and updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Assume A is always precisely n times as wide as B, you can use the following code to generate c:

```
 A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6; 7 8 9 10 11 12 ]
 B = [ 13 14; 15 16 ]

 NA = size(A, 2);
 NB = size(B, 2);
 n = NA / NB;

 # Make a combined array
 AB = [A B]

 # Pick columns from A and B part in AB, respectively
 colsA = reshape(1:NA, [n, NB])
 colsB = reshape(1:NB, [1, NB]) + NA

 cols = [colsA; colsB] 


 c = AB(:, cols(:))
```

The basic idea is to first concatenate A and B horizontally as AB. Then c would equal `AB(:, [1:n, NA+1, (1:n)+n, NA+2, (1:n)+2*n, NA+3 ... ])` The column index array is produced by interleaving `[1:n (1:n)+n, (1:n)+2*n... ]` and `[NA+1, NA+2, NA+3 ... ]`; both can be conveniently constructed using reshape like above.

Comment: Thanks, but the matrix is not always n times as wide.

Comment: I see. It would be better though if you were a little bit more specific about _exactly_ how flexible you want the solution to be. Otherwise, the answerers are forced to make (often incorrect) assumptions.

Comment: Your correct, so I added another case and updated my question.